# How do I convert an Integer to ctypes.c_byte in python

Tags: python, kernel

I am trying to use Read and Write ProcessMemory form `kernel32.dll` in Python 3.5.

I got `ReadProcessMemory` working like this:

```
def ReadMemInt(adress):
    buffer = (ctypes.c_byte * 8)()
    bytesRead = ctypes.c_ulonglong(0)
    if ctypes.windll.kernel32.ReadProcessMemory(processHandle, adress, buffer, len(buffer), ctypes.byref(bytesRead)):
        return struct.unpack('Q', buffer)[0]
    else:
        return -1
```

Now I am kind of stuck on getting WPM to work since I don't know how to convert my Variables into bytes...

This is what I've tried so far:

```
def WiteMemInt(adress, Val):
    buffer = ctypes.c_byte(Val)
    bytesRead = ctypes.c_ulonglong(0)
    ctypes.windll.kernel32.WriteProcessMemory(processHandle, adress, buffer, 4, ctypes.byref(bytesRead))
```

I hope the question suits the level of StackOverflow!

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what you mean by "kind of stuck", for instance errors encountered when running your code?

Comment: The code runs but doesn't work...

Comment: please, this is important!

Answer (score 0):

Got it working:

```
    def WriteMem(self, adress, Val, type):
        buffer = (ctypes.c_byte * self.GetSize(type))(*struct.pack(type, Val))
        bytesRead = ctypes.c_ulonglong(0)
        if ctypes.windll.kernel32.WriteProcessMemory(self.processHandle, adress, buffer, len(buffer), ctypes.byref(bytesRead)):
            return True
        else:
            return False
```